# How to upload the images/MP4 videos/PDF using Jmeter 4.0

Tags: jmeter-4.0

Unable to upload the images using Jmeter. Getting below error when reply the script.
The request could not be understood due to malformed syntax.","error_code":1000[![v4/jobs/imports/]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use Files upload tab in [http sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) to upload any files not Parameters tab.

[image]

Give Complete path if your file does not resides on bin folder of JMeter and enter parameter name, mime type .

more info :

[File uploading with JMeter](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/08/file-upload-with-jmeter/)

Comment: STill I am getting the error message The request could not be understood due to malformed syntax.","error_code":1000

Comment: I observed below error: any suggestion{"exception_body":{"http_response_code":500,"message":"An internal server error occurred.","debug_message":"For input string: \"162872 \"","error_code":1000}}